# Unsupervised Learning in R? Classify Matrices - what is the right package?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

Recently I watched a lot of Stanford's hilarious [Open Classroom's](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/) video lectures. Particularly the part about unsupervised Machine Learning got my attention. Unfortunately it stops were it might get even more interesting.

Basically I am looking to classify discrete matrices by an unsupervised algorithm. Those matrices just contain discrete values of the same range. Let's say I have 1000s of 20x15 matrices that with values ranging from 1-3. I just started to read through the literature and I feel that image classification is way more complex (color histograms) and that my case is rather a simplification of what is done there.

I also looked at the [Machine Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html) and [Cluster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) Cran Task Views but do not know where to start with a practical example.

So my question is: which package / algorithm would be a good pick to start playing around and working on the problem in R?

EDIT: 
I realized that I might have been to imprecise: My matrix contains discrete choice data – so mean clustering might(!) not be the right idea. I do understand with what you said about vectors and observation but I am hoping for some function that accepts matrices or data.frames, because I have several observations over time.

EDIT2: 
I realize that a package / function, introduction that focuses on unsupervised classification of categorical data is what would help me the most right now.

Comment: `kmeans` in `library(class)` and `hclust` - these are the two basic ones.

Comment: does that work for categorical data too ?

Comment: @ran2: any clustering algorithm works for categorical data with the right settings. Using a 1-of-K coding is a Good Idea and if your clustering package offers multiple distance metrics, you might want to try L1 distance instead of Euclidean.

Comment: @larsmans, thx! do you have a good read / starting on what you just explained?

Comment: @ran2: most of my ML knowledge is from practice and discussion with colleagues. I bet you can find a lot of info in [ESL](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), though.

Answer (score 0):

> ... classify discrete matrices by an unsupervised algorithm

You must mean cluster them. Classification is commonly done by supervised algorithms.

> I feel that image classification is way more complex (color histograms) and that my case is rather a simplification of what is done there

Without knowing what your matrices represent, it's hard to tell what kind of algorithm you need. But a starting point might be to flatten your 20*15 matrices to produce length-300 vectors; each element of such a vector would then be a *feature* (or *variable*) to base a clustering on. This is the way must ML packages, including the `Cluster` package you link to, work: "In case of a matrix or data frame, each row corresponds to an observation, and
each column corresponds to a variable."

Comment: Sorry for being to imprecise. Edited my post now.

Comment: Historically, what's now generally known as clustering used to be called classification. There's even a fairly well-known textbook by that name: http://www.amazon.com/Classification-Chapman-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/1584880139

Answer (score 0):

So far I found `daisy` from the `cluster` package respectively the argument "gower" which refers to `Gower's similarity coefficient` to handle multiple modes of data. Gower seems to be a fairly only distance metric, still it's what I found for use with categorical data.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to start from here : http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html

Comment: Who +1'd this? I don't downvote because y'all are just trying to help me to get a grip on this. I mean I just posted that link in my original post. If it was meant to say RTFM, writing exactly that would have been honest.

Comment: i didn't notice CRAN ML site referenced in your original post....!

Comment: Don't worry :) I am not blaming you, just wondered about the random up. In the meantime I got quite some information, but it was relatively (compared to other R issues) hard to find a starting point. there's really sooo much around – especially if you do not know very exactly what you are looking for. Really found some packages and will hopefully learn enough to summarize it here later.